# org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value With @One to Many join table in hibernate 5.4.5.Final

Tags: hibernate

I have 3 Classes that shares one to many -- Many to One relationship with a join table.
Here are the mappings,

HardwarePackage.java

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "HDWR_PKG_DVC_XREF", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "HDWR_PKG_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "DVC_ID") })
private Set<Device> devices;
```

Device.java

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "HDWR_PKG_DVC_XREF", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "DVC_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "HDWR_PKG_ID") })
private HardwarePackage hardwarePackage;
```

HardwarePackageDeviceXREF.java

```
@Id
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "DVC_ID")
private Device device;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "HDWR_PKG_ID")
private HardwarePackage hardwarePackage;
```

When I try to save the Device.java object without creating a HardwarePackage.java object I get error,

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.deere.isg.dm.domain.commserv.Device.hardwarePackage

This used to work just fine with hibernate 5.0.3.Final version, It seems they changed something in 5.0.5.Final but not sure what and why.

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason.

There is a property that you have to set to avoid checking nullability,

```
<prop key="hibernate.check_nullability">false</prop>
```

Though not sure why the defaults are different between 2 versions.